# Shortcode with multiple paramaters

Tags: shortcode

I'm designing a site and I have encountered quite a big issue which I've tried to solve using shortcodes. This shortcode calls a slideshow which can have between 0-5 images.

The actual shortcode has been designed, and tested. It works absolutely fine. The issue I'm having is with the `add_shortcode` wordpress API. Here is the code I have at the moment.

```
function soc_custom_section_widget_func( $atts ) 
{
    $image_one = "";
    $image_two = "";
    $image_three = "";
    $image_four = "";
    $image_five = "";

    if(sizeof($atts) > 0)
    {
        $image_one = $atts[image_one];      
    }
    if(sizeof($atts) > 1)
    {
        $image_two = $atts[image_two];  
    }
    if(sizeof($atts) > 2)
    {
        $image_three = $atts[image_three];
    }
    if(sizeof($atts) > 3)
    {
        $image_four= $atts[image_four]; 
    }
    if(sizeof($atts) > 4)
    {
        $image_five = $atts[image_five];
    }

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'image_one' => '',
        'image_two' => '',
        'image_three' => '',
        'image_four' => '',
        'image_five' => ''
    ), $atts );

    return do_shortcode('[soc_custom_section_widget image_one='.$atts['image_one'].' image_two='.$atts['image_two'].' image_three='.$atts['image_three'].' image_four='.$atts['image_four'].' image_five='.$atts['image_five'].']');
}
add_shortcode( 'soc_custom_section_widget', 'soc_custom_section_widget_func' );
```

I've been attempting to solve this issue for the past couple of hours. At the moment when I refresh the page it just shows everything as blank under the header.

Thanks.

Comment: First, You are making a recursion, `[soc_custom_section_widget]` is supposed to call another shortcode? because it is calling itself rather than returning content.

Comment: Ahh. [soc_custom_section_widget] is an actual shortcode. All I want to do is output it!

Comment: Got it. So that shortcode can take up-to 5 img and you're making a custom shortcode to use?

Comment: Exactly. Seem to be eluding me this evening.

Comment: Can you try this http://pastebin.com/C97574FC and now use `[soc_custom_section_widget_custom]`?

Comment: It just seems to be returning this on the page `[soc_custom_section_widget image_one="http://crane.spotoncreative.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/IQWrench2.jpg" image_two="http://crane.spotoncreative.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/IQWrench2.jpg"]` The image names are correct by the way!

Comment: Just to "avoid extended discussions in comments", isn't that what you're opting to get? I suppose `soc_custom_section_widget` shortcode exists by default, or you are creating it and you have a function callback to pass images to?

Comment: So, I have a widget which I can use to display a slideshow of 1-5 images. I wanted to call this in any post by making use of the add_widget function call in the WP API. So, what you have given me is what I thought I needed, but I guess behind the scenes I do have a widget called [soc_custom_section_widget], but not a shortcode.

Comment: Alright lol, so it's a different topic, I am guessing in the widget you are giving fields where to upload images or insert URLs. Look through the widget controller code, there must be a function or something to use or if there's a way to see the plugin or theme code.